# UniqueIdentifier format when indexing with mongorive in ElasticSearch

Tags: .net, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am a .Net developer using elasticsearch with mongo river. I am able to index mongodb collection successfully. But the issue I am facing is that all the UniqueIdentifiers in my mongodb are .Net GUIDs. In the indexed documents when I look for these fields they are in Java UUID format. Is there a work around so that I can get them as .Net GUIDs. Any help in this matter is really appreciated.

Comment: What's the format of the GUIDs? You could just use strings rather than specifically using a GUID type as well.

Comment: If i store them as strings when I query from mongodb in c# it is a problem because of lack of proper text based search in mongodb.

Comment: You can query them as strings just fine in MongoDB (assuming the field is indexed). So, I don't understand what you mean by "lack of proper text based search." (And while there is a preview of full-text search in 2.4+, you definitely wouldn't need it to search for an ID in MongoDB).

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue that UUIDs are stored in different formats between different language drivers: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-403

In later versions of the Java driver you will be able to query and insert by .NET UUIDs, but at this time you cannot.  Nor is there a utility to convert the UUIDs from one type to another.